# Resizing faux-bold text makes it ... bolder

Tags: adobe-photoshop, bold

I'm using Scriptina Pro on a design; it’s a fairly thin font. I used faux bold and now it’s perfect. However, when I resize the entire graphic to be smaller, the text turns huge, puffy even. Any idea how to keep faux bold and resize it? Or is there another way to make a skinny font bold?

Comment: What if you convert the layer to Smart object and transform the Smart object?

Comment: This sounds like you added a stroke to the type. The Faux-bold button on the character palette will resize proportionally. A stroke effect (or shadow etc) applied to the type layer will keep its set size: a 10 px stroke will still be 10 px. I think joonas is suggesting a smart layer will allow for proportional resizing of these layers.

Comment: I transformed it to a smart object and it resized just fine. =) Thanks Joonas!

Answer (score 1):

Goto Illustrator. There you can add a stroke to a text and stroke widths can be made scalable in the preferences:

[image]

1. A sample text having a thin font
2. Selected the textbox and added a thick stroke
3. Scaled the textbox to smaller size. The strokes are not scalable in Illustrators's preferences
4. Changed in the preferences stroke widths to scalable, made a copy of textbox 2 and scaled it to smaller size. Box 3 were not affected.